# Edit XML file in BASH

Tags: xml, linux, bash, xml-namespaces

Is there a way to edit an XML file in bash

```
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.5" default-virtual-server="default-host" instance-id="node1" native="false">
            <configuration>
                <jsp-configuration mapped-file="false" x-powered-by="false"/>
            </configuration>
            <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http" max-connections="3000"/>
            <connector name="ajp" protocol="AJP/1.3" scheme="ajp" socket-binding="ajp" max-connections="3000"/>
            <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="false">
                <alias name="localhost"/>
                <access-log pattern="%T %h %l %u %A %v %t %r %s %b %S %I"/>
            </virtual-server>
        </subsystem>
```

I wanted to replace the "node1" in the xml file with "APP1", is there a way to do this directly in bash ?

is there any module i need to install on my linux vm to get this working ?

Comment: BTW, if you used XMLStarlet, this might look like `xmlstarlet ed -N jb=urn:jboss:domain:web:1.5 -u '//jb:subsystem[@instance-id="node1"]/@instance-id' -v APP1`

Comment: thanks @CharlesDuffy, let me try this. thanks a lot for your help! :)

Comment: Hi @CharlesDuffy, it did not work